# Where to configure which calendar is displayed by the default time & calendar indicator applet?

Tags: gnome, evolution, calendar

I recently upgraded to 14.04 and I love it.

One thing is bothering me though: I notice that the default time & calendar indicator applet now displays calendar events. It's currently showing events from my Google calendar account. The thing is, I don't remember configuring this anywhere, and I can't see where it's getting my credentials from. How is the applet logging in to my Google account?

I don't have evolution installed and I've not added my account details to on-line services under settings. The Google Calendar web app has not been configured either.

I guess this must be a gconf setting from a previous version of Ubuntu. Any ideas how I can change the config?

Thanks..

Comment: Install Evolution. You will see which calendars are enabled. Delete those you don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Evolution

`sudo apt-get install evolution`

Open it. You will see which calendars are enabled. Delete those you don't need it.